# using printf to create a header

Tags: linux, bash, printf

I am very new to this, so my apologies in advance if this is a simple question.
I would like to create an output using 'printf' that would look like below:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------
#TEXT1                                #TEXT2
#--------------------------------------------------------
```

I would really appreciate if someone could give me some hints as to how to do this.

Comment: You say it is a 'header'; what are you going to use to format the 'body'?  For example, if you will use `printf "%-20s  %s\n" "$text1" "$text2"`, then the centre header line should be `printf "%-20s  %s\n" "#TEXT1" "#TEXT2"` to align everything.

Comment: yes that is what I am after. what does the "%-20s  %s\n" do? Also is there a way of printing let's say 40 '-' instead of typing them in one by one?

Comment: by the way in the body of the output I have the text under TEXT1, the text under TEXT2 is three TAB's away. I am hoping to align these two columns under TEXT1 and TEXT2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using long strings with a specific number of characters.

```
dashes=$(printf "%0.s-" {1..55})
printf "#$dashes\n#TEXT1%32s#TEXT2\n#$dashes-\n" " "
```

See [Bash-Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) for detailed information on `printf` command in `bash`.

### How it works

- `dashes=$(printf "%0.s-" {1..55})` - uses [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) and [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to create a string variable of 55 consecutive `-` characters.
- `\n` - prints a newline character
- `%32s` - prints 32 `" "` characters

### Update

To print three tabs between `#TEXT1` and `#TEXT2`:

```
dashes=$(printf "%0.s-" {1..55})
printf "#$dashes\n#TEXT1\t\t\t#TEXT2\n#$dashes-\n" " "
```

- `\t` represents a tab character.

Comment: Thanks for that. That doesn't seem to work! How would I be able to print TEXT1 and TEXT2 [tab][tab][tab] apart?

Comment: Please see my update for printing three tabs instead of 32 spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for such trivial questions. I'm just beginning to learn.

Comment: Also I found this to be a simple solution: printf ("%s\t\t\t%s\n", "TEXT1", "TEXT2"), this way I can keep the same format for the other lines in the body of the output of the script.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  I didn't simply because I'm lazy and like to write less characters, although using `%s` is preferred when the string is variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the strings with newlines at the end.

```
printf '#-------------------------------------------------------\n'
printf '#TEXT1                                #TEXT2\n'
printf '#--------------------------------------------------------\n'
```

You can also use `echo`, since there's no formatting in the strings. Then you don't need `\n` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this,

```
$ printf "#-------------------------------------------------------\n#TEXT1                                #TEXT2\n#--------------------------------------------------------\n";
#-------------------------------------------------------
#TEXT1                                #TEXT2
#--------------------------------------------------------
```